# How to avoid error -> Duplicate entry

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

table user (with id, username, password, is_admin)

my controller (where i adding)

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:respondent])
#   entered     = User.find(:all, :conditions => ["email = ?", @user])
    render :json => @user.to_ext_json(:success => @user.save)
    return false 
  end
```

When i pasting the same email, i got this:

```
pre>Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry 'sam@sa.com' for key 'email': INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `updated_at`, `email`) VALUES('2011-05-05 09:05:57', '2011-05-05 09:05:57', 'sam@sa.com')</pre>
```

How to avoid this? What i should write in controller (some if?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either validate uniqueness in your model

```
validates :email, :uniqueness => :true
```

or you can rescue RecordNotUnique in your controller like so

```
begin
  # create user
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique => e
  # handle duplicate entry
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not do that in the controller. These are the validations you should be doing in your model. Please read through [this guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) to understand how to go about it.