# Require and validate email conditionally based on the existence of another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm allowing the email to be optional sometimes, depending on whether there is a `phone` field or not. If there is such - do not validate for presence, if there is not - validate it. Here's the code:

```
# model.rb
validates :email, length: {maximum: 255},
        uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false},
        email: true

validates_presence_of :email, unless: Proc.new {|user| user.phone? }
```

The problem is the way this is, if the user submits an empty `email` field, it will error with `Email has already been taken` and `Email is not an email`.

I also have an `email_validator.rb`:

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attr_name, value)
    unless value =~ MY_EMAIL_REGEX
      record.errors.add(attr_name, 'is not an email')
    end
  end
end
```

I want to:

- Validate the email format only when there is some value in the input
- Allow blank (or) nil when the email is not required (e.g. phone exists)

Answer (score 1):

You have used `Proc` in one validation of `email` but not in other validation, use in both :

```
validates :email, length: {maximum: 255},
        uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false},
        allow_blank: true, # This option will let validation pass if the attribute's value is blank?, like nil or an empty string
        email: true, unless: Proc.new {|user| user.phone? }

validates_presence_of :email, unless: Proc.new {|user| user.phone? }
```

You can merge both validation like this:

```
validates :email, length: {maximum: 255},
           uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false},
           presence: true,
           allow_blank: true, # This option will let validation pass if the attribute's value is blank?, like nil or an empty string  
           email: true, unless: Proc.new {|user| user.phone? }
```

Comment: Thanks! Part of the question though is to allow blank email, which in this case won't work and the second user that registers without an email will get `Duplicate entry '' for key 'index_users_on_email'`

Comment: @abpetkov : updated my answer, for more info on allow_blank : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#allow-blank

Comment: Even when allowing nil and blank, I get the `Duplicate entry` error.

Comment: @abpetkov : check this answer for `Duplicate Entry`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895411/how-to-avoid-error-duplicate-entry